# Flutter file write takes too long

Tags: flutter, performance, persistence

I'm trying to write an application that tries to provide an offline capability for a vast number of records (above 20m).

I've tried to do it using `sqflite` and tests show that it's not feasible since it either takes very long to write (if the index are predefined) or takes too long to index (after the inserts)

So I've decided to use the file system and since I'm only going to query with an id, use the file name as `id` and try to find the record.

but this time, the main problem is, file write operation takes very very long. I'm using `File(filePath).writeAsString` API and for 50 to 120 char strings, it sometimes takes more than 100ms.

I'm trying to utilize the isolations for better performance but it still does not help very much.

Is there a better approach or an file manipulation API available for this kind of an operation.

Comment: If only file writing is the bottleneck, you don't need to use isolates.. `writeAsString` is asynchronous and should not block. afaik isolate communication isn't very fast either.. so keep everything in one isolate could actually be faster.. although i/o will generally be quite slow.. 20m for a mobile app sounds pretty exhaustive.. maybe you should try to just fetch a subset of the data which is actually required..